# Big o with recursion python

Tags: recursion, big-o

```
def maxnum(l):
    if len(l)==1:
       return l[0]
    else:
        largest=maxnum(l[1:])
        if l[0]>largest:
            return l[0]
        else:
            return largest
```

I wonder the big O notation for this recursion(is that n-1?). Thanks!

Comment: It's *not* `O(n - 1)`, big-oh ignores constant factors.

Comment: so for 10 elements， the answer would be 9 times？

Comment: What? Your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean "9 times"? How does that relate to Big-O? Big O is about asymptotic, worst-case behavior, not about counting how many times you expect some loop to run...

Comment: I mean for 10elements，the worest scenario is 9times to figure out？

Comment: Big-Oh notations concerns finding an upper bound to *asymptotic behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

The recurrence relation for the sample code is 

**T(n)=T(n-1)+c**

When you solve this relation as

```
 T(n)=T(n-1)+c
     =(T(n-2)+c)+c
     =((T(n-3)+c)+c)+c 
      .
      .
      .
     =T(1)+n*c
     =n*c
```

Therefore time complexity is **TC=O(n*c)**
 that is equal to **O(n)**